# infinite input c++ calculator to end the calculation need one more int

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a calculator with infinite inputs which I kinda did but I have a problem...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, sum = 0.0;
    char op;

    cout << sum;

    while (op != '=') 
    {
        cin >> op >> a;
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                sum =  sum+a;
                cout << sum;
                break;
            case '-':
                sum = sum-a;
                cout << sum;
                break;
            case '/':
                sum = sum/a;
                cout << sum;
                break;
            case '*':
                sum= sum*a;
                cout << sum;
                break;
            case '=':
                cout << sum;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To finish the first calculation you need to type not only the operator but also an `int`. So it would look something like this:

0+3
3=[random int]
sum

I would like to get rid of the [random int] to finish.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `op` before it has been initialized. Therefore its value is *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for your problem you need a little more advanced parser that can handle single operator input. Try reading a full line, and then parse that one operator/operand at a time ([`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) could be used for that).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you store an entire line in a string (you must `#include<string>`)

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);

string op;
string a;
```

Then you can get the data from the string:

```
if(string.length > 1)
{
    op = line.substr(0,1);
    a  = line.substr(1,string.length);
}
else op = line.substr(0,1)
```

Then you convert the op to char:

```
char chOp = line[0];
```

Convert the string a to int:

```
int intA = std::stoi(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Some programmer dude is completely correct. A proper parser is the only reliable way to go. Below is an example of a brittle , that is to say 'easily broken', parser for the kind of input I think you're expecting. Cleverer people than I could probably write it better. Note the required error checking and assumptions within the code.

I've also taken the liberty to clean up your original main() a small bit.

Hope this inspires you to learn boost::spirit or any of the excellent C++ parsers out there.

```
    using namespace std;

    bool
    get_input_from_cin(char & op, double & d)
    {
    static const char * OPERATORS="+-/*=";
    char lc ='\0';
    char d_buffer[64]; // where we'll store the number
    size_t d_buffer_counter = 0;
    memset(d_buffer,'\0',sizeof(d_buffer));  // initialize it to nulls
    for (char lc = ' '; lc != '\n'; cin.get(lc))
    { // loop gathering characters until you get a newline.

          if ( strchr(OPERATORS,lc) != nullptr)
          { // if we're expecting an operator and we find it then save it
                op = lc; // what happens if we get more than one operator before a new line?
          }
          else if ( ' ' == lc )
          {
                ; // No Operation : consume spaces with no action
          }
          else
          { // we assume a double, save the digits. Check they are digits using isdigit(..) or some call.
              d_buffer[d_buffer_counter++] = lc;
              if ( d_buffer_counter == sizeof(d_buffer) )
              { // issue a warning in here somehow
                  return false;
              }
          }
     }

    if ( '\0' == op )
    { // no operator included!
        return false;
    }

    if ( '\0' == d_buffer[0] )
    { // no number included!
        return false;
    }

    d = atof(d_buffer);
    return true;
    }

    int main()
    {
    double a = 0.0, sum = 0.0; // you're not using b or c, better not to declare them
    char op;

    cout    << sum;
    op = '\0'; // initialize 
    while (op != '=')
    {

        if (false == get_input_from_cin(op, a))
        {
            if ('=' == op)
            {
                cout << sum;
                return 0;
            }
            cerr << "Input parse error." << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        switch (op)
        {
        case '+':
            sum = sum + a;
            cout << sum;
            break;
        case '-':
            sum = sum - a;
            cout << sum;
            break;
        case '/':
            sum = sum / a;
            cout << sum;
            break;
        case '*':
            sum = sum*a;
            cout << sum;
            break;
        case '=':
            cout << sum;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```