# Is there a way to assign math operators as variables and call then back later in the program as math operators?

Tags: c++, variables, math, operators

I want to make a calculator program that when executed only uses the number and operator buttons on my keyboard. Specifically using the '=' sign as a sentinel that ends the program and outputs the answer to the display.

This is an assignment I have for a basic CSCI course.

> The goal is for the user to input a number, then a '+' or a '-' sign
>   and then another number and so forth until they hit '='.

then the answer of the two(or more #s) when compared to the operator(s) is displayed. I've tried to set the input '+' or'-' as char variables but cannot call them back as math operators later in the program.

*once program is running this is what expected output is*

3.0 + 4.0 - 2.0 =
**The answer is 5.0**

Comment: If you have the (calculator) operator as character, then you can simply `switch` or `if`/`else` on it, calling in each branch the appropriate (c++) operator on the (c++) variables holding the (calculator) operands.

Comment: Unless you care about operator precedence and parentheses, in which case it isn't nearly as simple. @uneven_mark

Comment: @user207421 I only meant that one doesn't need to store the operators as corresponding (c++) functions/operators (in whatever parsed data structure), but that they can be stored as characters and interpreted via conditionals, where ever that interpretation is needed. I didn't intend to say anything about the parsing (or lexing) itself.

Comment: This problem was already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184882/infinite-input-c-calculator-to-end-the-calculation-need-one-more-int